# How to show current URL inside embed

Tags: javascript, html

`<embed src="snippet.html">` - I need to insert the custom url(othersite.com/directory/something/) + "search part" of the current URL inside src attribute. I get that something like "console.log(window.location.search)" can help, but how could I connect/insert that to be inside src?

In short, my embed code output should looks like: `<embed src="othersite.com/directory/something/astalavista">` , when the current URL looks like this mysite.com/info/astalavista

How should my HTML code look like?

I use Wordpress. Need HTML code. Thanks.

Comment: You need the pathname and split on `/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const loc = new URL(location.href);
const lastPath = loc.pathname.split('/').pop();
const embed = document.createElement('embed');
embed.src = `https://othersite.com/directory/something/${lastPath}`
document.body.appendChild(embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it right in-place in your HTML, maybe not the best JS ever, but you can go:

```
some of your html...
<script>
  let myUrl = "whatever"; // or echo some php variable here?
  window.write(`<embed src="snippet.html/${myUrl}">`);
</script>
carry on with your html...
```